# Problem fontspec/xetex-xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontspec

My editor is giving me a preambule file to work with. 
On my previous laptop (which has just been stolen), i was able to compile the file.

But on my new one, there is the following errors :

```
Runaway argument?
{\dim_set:Nn ##1{\fontdimen ##2##3}\dim_compare:nNnT ##1={0pt}{\settoheight \ET
C.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \__cs_generate_from_si
gnature:nnNNNn.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1504       \int_case:nnn
                           #2
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           The deprecated command '\int_case:nnn' has been o...
l.1504       \int_case:nnn
                           #2
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/deprecated-command"
! 
! The deprecated command '\int_case:nnn' has been or will be removed on
! 2015-07-14. Use instead '\int_case:nnF '.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! Type <return> to continue.
!...............................................  

l.1504       \int_case:nnn
                           #2
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.
| 
| Try typing <return> to proceed.
| If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
|...............................................

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.1504       \int_case:nnn #
                            2
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.
```

I found some related subject on this site. And use :

```
 \usepackage{expl3}
 \ExplSyntaxOn
 \cs_new_eq:NN \str_case:nnn \str_case:nnF
 \cs_new_eq:NN \str_case_x:nnn \str_case_x:nnF
 \cs_new_eq:NN \int_case:nnn \int_case:nnF
 \cs_set_eq:NN\tl_case:Nnn\tl_case:NnF
 \ExplSyntaxOff
```

It didn't work out for me. Thanks a lot for any answer!

Comment: Welcome, can you input the exact error from the log file including 4 or 5 lines above and below into the question?

Comment: Is your TeX distribution up to date?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try to input as your asking.
Yes my miktex is up to date (it's even the latest).
Ps : it's not well done, i dont know how to put the message error in a grey box as you did for me.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!